# При выполнении ajax запроса ошибка undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Как я понял ошибка где-то в ajax коде, хотя я не уверен. Иногда скрипт выполняется успешно, но сообщение на почту все равно не приходит.

html

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off" method="post" name="callback" id="form">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Заказать обратный звонок.</legend>
    <p><label for="name">ФИО <em>*</em> </label><input type="text" name="name" required class="input"></p>
    <p><label for="tel">Телефон <em>*</em> </label><input type="text" name="tel" required class="input"></p>
    <p id="zamech"><label for="message">Замечания</label><textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
    <p id="dop"><em>*</em> Поля обязательные для заполнения.</p>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Заказать звонок">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function() {
            var form = $(this);
            var form_data = form.serialize();;
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function() {
                    var message = "Обратный звонок заказан!";
                    alert(message);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                   alert('Ошибка: '+xhr.responseText);
            },    
        });
    });
});    
</script>
```

send.php

```
<?php
        $to = 'pochta@pochta.com';
        $subject = 'Обратный звонок.';
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>ФИО: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
                        <p>Телефон: '.$_POST['tel'].'</p>    
                        <p>Замечания: '.$_POST['message'].'</p>                    
                    </body>
                </html>';
        $email = 'pochta@nepochta.com';
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: '. $email . "\r\n"; // от кого
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Ну так вы ничего и невозвращаете в аякс что бы проверить есть ли ошибка. Да и данные не валидируете.

Comment: Что именно за ошибка происходит в браузере/на сервере? Что значит "скрипт выполняется успешно, но сообщение на почту не отправляется"? Как вы проверяете эту самую успешность выполнения?

Comment: `success: function(data)`, `data` и будет ответом от сервера

Answer (score 2):

Я надеюсь вы не на локальном сервере это все проверяете.Потому что на локальном сервере SMTP сервер настроен так что он caм не отправляет sms ,a сохраняет его в файл.

```
var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
```

Смотрите в консоли -> Network.Если true,то все ок, к коду претензий нет.
Посоветую вместо mail() использовать imap_mail() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-mail.php

Проверит настройки SMTP сервера(port , ...)

Да и чтобы твой ajax мог обработать запрос надо возвращать json

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))?json_encode(['succss'=>true]):json_encode(['succss'=>false])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo json_encode($result);
```

В аяксе добавьте `dataType : 'json'` и в `success:function(data)` проверяйте

```
if(data) alert('Отправлено')
```